# azure-network_interface says variable is undefined

Tags: ansible

We switched to ansible 2.10
Before it was azure_rm_networkinterface_facts (working) now is azure_rm_networkinterface_info

```
- name:                            "Get facts for network interface by it's name"
  azure_rm_networkinterface_facts:
    resource_group:                "{{ target_resourcegroup }}"
    name:                          "{{ target_nic_name }}"

- name:                            "Define private IP address"
  set_fact:
    private_ip_address:            "{{ ansible_facts | json_query(query) }}"
  vars:
    query:                         "azure_networkinterfaces[0].properties.ipConfigurations[0].properties.privateIPAddress"
  when:                            azure_networkinterfaces|length > 0
```

Error I get is:

```
4  TASK [azure_preconditions : Define private IP address] *************************
00:01:38.844  [0;31mfatal: [40.118.86.58]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'azure_networkinterfaces|length > 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (azure_networkinterfaces|length > 0): 'azure_networkinterfaces' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PA-28544-ansible-version-upgrade/roles/azure_preconditions/tasks/main.yml': line 143, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name:                               \"Define private IP address\"\n  ^ here\n"}[0m
00:01:38.844
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`azure_networkinterfaces` seems to be a return value of `azure_rm_networkinterface_facts` so it's normal that it doesn't exist...

I'd write a playbook like this:

```yaml
- name: "Get facts for network interface by it's name"
  azure_rm_networkinterface_facts:
    resource_group:                "{{ target_resourcegroup }}"
    name:                          "{{ target_nic_name }}"
  register: output
```

I suggest you debug the `output` variable to check your return values. I don't know the version of Azure you are using and a lot of changes can exist depending on it.

```yaml
- name:  "Display return value"
  debug:
    msg: "{{ output }}"
```

You could play with `output.azure_networkinterfaces`  or `output.networkinterfaces`

Following the last documentation, its seems `azure_rm_networkinterface_fact` is deprecated, replaced by  `azure_rm_networkinterface_info`

[azure_rm_networkinterface_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/azure_rm_networkinterface_info_module.html#azure-rm-networkinterface-info-module)